# Alarm clock with timer?

Tags: android, timer, alarm, countdowntimer

I am trying to develop my own countdown alarm app on android. I have some questions:

- How do I create an alarm with a fixed time (50 minutes) so that when I press the start button, it automatically sets an alarm in 50 minutes?
- How do I make a countdown timer that alarms and plays a sound when it reaches zero?
- How do I repeat this alarm?

I am new, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) Object. Something like this:

```
new CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){

    @Override
    public void onFinish(){
        //do finished code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        //do code every second or so it counts down here
    }

}
```

Remember that the variables are in milliseconds, so 1000 milliseconds equals 1 second.

Comment: How do I make the alarm 50 miniutes?